# How do I find the cause of an IIS/SQL timeout?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, web-services, iis

I have a web service sitting on IIS that has been quite happy for months but now I'm getting timeouts and I don't know how to diagnose what the problem is.

The client sends up basic information in a 'heartbeat' message to IIS which then updates this in a SQL database (on a different server). There are 250 clients in the wild, all sending up their heartbeat every 5 minutes ... so there's only 250 rows in the table, with appropriate indexing on the column being used for the update.

Ordinarily it only takes 50-100ms to do the update, but since last week you can see that the response time in the IIS log has increased and I'm also getting timeouts too.

Nothing has changed with the setup so I don't know what I'm looking for to determine the reason. The error I get back is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred while updating
> the entries. See the inner exception for details.An error occurred
> while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
> details.Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
> completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The
> statement has been terminated.The wait operation timed out

Any advice on where to start looking? I did enable the failed request log trace in IIS but I don't know what it all means if I'm perfectly honest. The difference between a successful requiest and a failed one is that the request log stops after the 'AspNetStart' entry.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: Is that the only interaction between IIS and the SQL Server, or are there other queries which are working properly and this is the only one which is a problem?

Comment: There are other queries that are working properly but also other services that do give the occasional timeout or handshaking error. It's not consistent.

Comment: Does anything else use the table - i.e. could something else have a lock on it which is preventing your query from being processed in a timely fashion?

Comment: No, only this web service uses that table.

Comment: You'll need to figure out if it's an SQL Server problem, an IIS problem, or an infrastructure problem (e.g. dodgy Ethernet cable). As other queries are working, I wouldn't think it's the cables. For the first one, perhaps a search for "sql server query has become slow" will give you somewhere to investigate, assuming you have sufficient access to the SQL Server.

Comment: Regarding the FaultException error, I suggest you use the [FaultContractAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to design your services to return strongly-typed SOAP faults (and not managed exception objects) for all fault cases in which you decide the client requires fault information

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons a service can gradually or suddenly become slow. Poor code structure can lead to things like memory leaks on the server, small enough they don't really show up or cause problems during testing, but when run over weeks/months start to stack up. Unauthorized requests could be targeting your server if this is a public-facing service, or has a link to public-facing services.

Things to look at:

- Does this happen at certain times of the day or throughout the day?

Is this a load issue that starts occurring when multiple users are sending updates concurrently?  250 users isn't a lot. Has the # of users grown over the last few months or has it been relatively stable since the start?

- What is the memory and CPU usage looking like on the Web server(s) and DB server?

This is the first clue to check to see if either server is under considerable load. From there you can investigate why it might be under load or if it possibly needs a bit more grunt to deal with the load. Look at the running processes. If these servers are managed by an IT department or such some culprits can include things like Virus Scanners hogging resources. (I.e. policy changes in the last few months have lead to additional load on the servers)

- What recovery model is your database set up for?
- What is the size of your Tx Log (.mdx file)
- Do you have a regular scheduled database backup and index maintenance?

This is one that new projects tend to forget. An empty database is small and has no Tx Log history being recorded, but as it runs over time that Tx Log grows silently in the background, especially with Full recovery. Larger Tx Logs can lead to slower performance over time especially if the log file needs to be enlarged. A good thing to check is whether the log file is set to grow by a # of bytes or percentage. Percentage is I believe the default but this can cause exponential "grow" time/space issues so it's better to set it to a fixed size per grow. You'll want regular backups being done that allow the Tx Log to reset. Ideally don't shrink the file if the Log size between backups stays consistent.

- How many records across all tables are being inserted or updated in a given day?

This is important to build a picture of how much the database will be tracking through the day between backups. You may have 250 clients, but every heartbeat is potentially updating a row and inserting others.

- What are you using for PKs for inserted records? (Ints vs. UUIDs) If using UUIDs are you using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` or `NEWID()`/`Guid.New()`?

GUIDs can be a time bomb for indexing if done poorly. A GUID combined with `NEWID()` or `Guid.New()` will lead to considerable index fragmentation when inserting rows. Provided the GUIDs are not visible to clients you should use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. If IDs are set via code then there are implementations you can find to generate sequential GUIDs. (It's a matter of re-arranging the parts that make up the GUID) Regular index maintenance is a requirement for using UUID columns in indexed fields.

- Are you using Dependency Injection in your web service?
- What is the lifetime scope of the DbContexts performing the updates?

This is a potential time bomb for web servers if the lifetime scope for a DbContext is set up incorrectly. You want a DbContext to be alive for no longer than it is needed. At a maximum the lifetime scope should be set to PerRequest. A DbContext set up for Singleton for instance would be tracking entities across requests. The more entities a DbContext is tracking, the slower read and update operations become. This would be a possible culprit if the web server memory usage is climbing.

- Are you running an SQL Profiler?

In a test environment with nothing else touching the database, running scenarios through the application with an SQL Profiler can reveal potential issues such as unexpected queries being kicked off due to things like lazy loading. For one operation you might expect one or a small number of queries to be run, only to find dozens or even hundreds. Multiply this across concurrent requests and you have a recipe for the database server to say "Just sit down and wait, dammit!" :)  Any queries you don't expect based on the code that is running should be investigated for either eager loading relationships or implementing projection. (Recommended for best performance)

- Do the web servers get restarted periodically?

For some tricky to debug issues and memory leaks, sometimes the easiest "fix" is to schedule regular restarts of the web server. It's a hack, but compared to the considerable cost of trying to track down memory leaks or fix up inefficient code that slows down over time, it is a cheap and effective fix. (At least while you do research options to address the issues and optimize the code)

That should give you a start into things to check with the service & database.